# Fill in between surrogate rows with Nan in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a `df`

```
elapse data datx
0,4,0
2,0,4
4,3,2
6,3,1
14,3,0
16,1,1
18,3,1
20,2,0
22,4,1
24,0,4
```

There are missing number in the columns `elapse`. Specifically the value `8,10,12`.

I would like to create and append the value `8,10,12` onto the column `elapse`, and assign `np.nan` at the other columns (i.e., `data`, and `datx`)

Which will result as below

```
0.00000,4.00000,0.00000
2.00000,0.00000,4.00000
4.00000,3.00000,2.00000
6.00000,3.00000,1.00000
8.00000,nan,nan
10.00000,nan,nan
12.00000,nan,nan
14.00000,3.00000,0.00000
16.00000,1.00000,1.00000
18.00000,3.00000,1.00000
20.00000,2.00000,0.00000
22.00000,4.00000,1.00000
24.00000,0.00000,4.00000
```

The following code should do the job

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

arr=np.concatenate([np.arange(0,8,2),np.arange(14,26,2)])
df=pd.DataFrame({'elapse': arr, 'data': np.random.randint(5,size=(len(arr))),
'datx': np.random.randint(5,size=(len(arr)))}, columns=['elapse', 'data','datx'])

g=df['elapse'].diff()
hh=g.idxmax()
interval_val=g.min()
missval_start=df.loc[hh-1,'elapse']+g.min()
missval_end=df.loc[hh+1,'elapse']-g.min()
new_val=np.arange(missval_start,missval_end,interval_val)
df_new=pd.DataFrame(new_val,columns=['elapse'])
df_new[['data','datx']]=np.nan

df=pd.concat([df,df_new])
df=df.sort_values('elapse')
```

But, I curious if other may have better suggestion than mine. This is because, in real case, the number of missing value is huge. Hence, I am more than happy for for more compact and efficient suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reindex` method:

```
df = df.set_index('elapse').reindex(range(df['elapse'].min(), df['elapse'].max()+1, 2)).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    elapse  data  datx
0        0   4.0   0.0
1        2   0.0   4.0
2        4   3.0   2.0
3        6   3.0   1.0
4        8   NaN   NaN
5       10   NaN   NaN
6       12   NaN   NaN
7       14   3.0   0.0
8       16   1.0   1.0
9       18   3.0   1.0
10      20   2.0   0.0
11      22   4.0   1.0
12      24   0.0   4.0
```

Comment: Hi @enke, the proposed suggestion does not work if I change `arr=np.concatenate([np.arange(0,2520,intervalval),np.arange(3610,6130,intervalval)])`.

Comment: @rpb what's the problem? what's `intervalval` here?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info provide. If intervalval=120, and arr=np.concatenate([np.arange(0,2520,intervalval),np.arange(3610,6130,intervalval)]). Existing value between 3610,6130 are all assigned as np.nan.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a new DataFarme with the new index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'data': {0: 4, 2: 0, 4: 3, 6: 3, 14: 3, 16: 1, 18: 3, 20: 2, 22: 4, 24: 0},
    'datx': {0: 0, 2: 4, 4: 2, 6: 1, 14: 0, 16: 1, 18: 1, 20: 0, 22: 1, 24: 4}
})

result = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 25, 2), data=df)
print(result)

#     data  datx
# 0    4.0   0.0
# 2    0.0   4.0
# 4    3.0   2.0
# 6    3.0   1.0
# 8    NaN   NaN
# 10   NaN   NaN
# 12   NaN   NaN
# 14   3.0   0.0
# 16   1.0   1.0
# 18   3.0   1.0
# 20   2.0   0.0
# 22   4.0   1.0
# 24   0.0   4.0
```

Comment: Hi @hilberts, thanks for the suggestion, however, your suggestion does not work if I change `arr=np.concatenate([np.arange(0,2520,intervalval),np.arange(3610,6130,intervalval)])`